# wrong output on Python code

Tags: python, python-3.5

Ok, i am a beginner in programming (obviously in Python) and i'm having a problem in my code. I've just wrote the code myself, using all the things i learned in tutorials.I am making a rock-paper-scissors game. Actually, it's working, but when i press on numpad '3', it shows me the code on the my else statement. Can someone help me with this?

```
import random

playerScore = 0
cpuScore = 0

def rpsGame():

    userInput = int(input("Choose (1)rock (2)paper (3)scissors: "))

    global playerScore
    global cpuScore
    cpuGuess = random.randint(1, 4)

    if userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 1:
        print("A draw! rock with a rock!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 2:
        print("CPU scores! paper never beats rock!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 3:
        print("Player scores! rock beats sharp scissors!")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 2 & cpuGuess == 1:
        print("Player! paper never beats rock!")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 2 & cpuGuess == 2:
        print("A draw! paper with a paper!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 2 & cpuGuess == 3:
        print("CPU scores! paper is cut with scissors!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 3 & cpuGuess == 1:
        print("CPU scores! scissors can't cut rock!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 3 & cpuGuess == 2:
        print("Player scores! Scissors beat paper")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)

    elif userInput == 3 & cpuGuess == 3:
        print("A draw! scissors with scissors!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)    
    else:
        print("Error")


while playerScore != 3 or cpuScore != 3:
    rpsGame()

if playerScore >= 3:
    print("Player wins!")

if cpuScore >= 3:
    print("You lose! The opponent won!")
```

[the python shell with the outputs of my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH6wC.jpg)

There's a link in the post which is the picture of the 'error'.I know, i did wrote error in the final else statement, so i would know if there's any problem.
Sorry for the long "else if" statements, i would change it when i watch and read more tutorials on Python.Thanks for considering :D

Comment: Half way through the `elif`s you switched from `and` to `&`. Why?

Comment: `randint` includes both of the endpoints, so about a quarter of the time, your code will have the computer pick 4, which doesn't match any of the `if`/`elif` conditions.

Comment: Whoa..didn't see the elif and the & sign there, thanks for noticing. To answer your question, is because my computer went off while i'm writing the code, and when i opened it again, the code was halfway saved, and i was thinking of using 'and' instead of 'elif', so i instead wrote 'and'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look at the random.randint function. Sadly it's not the same as range or slicing. So the reason it goes into the else statement is that the cpuGuess == 4.

Also, take a look at PEP8, I don't know why but I just cringe a little every time I see this upy-downy-hilly-case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (I added some code to only allow the input to be a number that is 1, 2 or 3).

```
import random

playerScore = 0
cpuScore = 0

def rpsGame():
    while True:
        try:
            userInput = int(input("Choose (1)rock (2)paper (3)scissors: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("That\'s not a number!")
        else:
            if 1 <= userInput < 3: 
                break
            else:
                print("Out of range. Try again")

    global playerScore
    global cpuScore
    cpuGuess = random.randint(1, 3)

    if userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 1:
        print("A draw! rock with a rock!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 2:
        print("CPU scores! paper never beats rock!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 1 and cpuGuess == 3:
        print("Player scores! rock beats sharp scissors!")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 2 and cpuGuess == 1:
        print("Player! paper never beats rock!")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 2 and cpuGuess == 2:
        print("A draw! paper with a paper!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 2 and cpuGuess == 3:
        print("CPU scores! paper is cut with scissors!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 3 and cpuGuess == 1:
        print("CPU scores! scissors can't cut rock!")
        cpuScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 3 and cpuGuess == 2:
        print("Player scores! Scissors beat paper")
        playerScore += 1
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)
    elif userInput == 3 and cpuGuess == 3:
        print("A draw! scissors with scissors!")
        print("Player Score:", playerScore, "CPU Score:", cpuScore)    
    else:
        print("Error")

while playerScore != 3 or cpuScore != 3:
    rpsGame()

if playerScore >= 3:
    print("Player wins!")

if cpuScore >= 3:
    print("You lose! The opponent won!")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU guess is having the CPU guess between 1 and 4.  Replace 4 with 3.

`cpuGuess = random.randint(1, 4)`

Should be:

`cpuGuess = random.randint(1, 3)`